# Find kth smallest element in matrix

Tags: c++11

I have problem/assignment about finding the `k-th` smallest element in a matrix.

I have a matrix `A(NxN)`, with `Aij = i* i + j* j` and `N = 10^6`. The upper time limit is 1sec, using `C++ 11` in `Visual Studio 2010`.

I have a solution where I sort the matrix and find it, but it takes `O(n*n*log(n*n) + K)` time and not enough memory.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is an O(n) solution.  Start simple.  What would you need to do if k = 1 (find the smallest element in the matrix)?  Since this is a school problem, I don't want to just give you the answer.  Good luck!

Comment: @Leonard There is no worst-case O(n) solution to a generic kth-order statistic. You can have it in average though.

Comment: There is a solution somewhere near O(n*log(k)) Generally it will be much closer to O(n), though, as most values of n won't actually invoke the log(k) feature. Enough clues.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You're right.  Thanks.  But I think telling the OP to try k=1 where there is an O(n) solution is a good hint.