# How to find element kth in array?

Tags: c++11, matrix

For array

```
A={2, 5, 5, 8, 10, 10, 13, 13,...}, (A={1^2+1^2, 1^2+2^2, 2^2+1^2, 2^2+2^2, 1^2+3^2, 3^2+1^2, 2^2+3^2, 3^2+2^2,...})
```

and number **K (K<=10^12)**.

Find kth element in array. I cannot create A array so i cannot find kth element.

Comment: Please take a look at [tour], [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Voted to close, please update with how the formula relates to the index, or what the sequence progression is.

Comment: It still might be an array with, let's say, 8K items (just as an example), initialized once with a formula, and later used 1000 per second - performance consideration. We don't know the application nor the considerations. No need to close. Not everyone is Bjarne Stroustrup (nor us). And this platform assists novice as expert individuals.

Comment: This is the same question you asked yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51366438/find-kth-smallest-element-in-matrix, why would you repeat it?

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you create (& initialize) the array like that:

```
int A[8]{ 2, 5, 5, 8, 10, 10, 13, 13 };
```

Or, even better, like that:

```
std::array<int, 8> A{ 2, 5, 5, 8, 10, 10, 13, 13 }; // In that case: #include <array>
```

As I see, your K value is a formula and I assume that K is not an index (i.e. index in that 8 size array is 0 - 7). So K is not the Kth element in the array. You should run on indexes 0 to 7 and compare each A[index] with K. When you reach to the index that satisfies the criteria, the (index+1) indicates the **n** element.

Comment: You've misunderstood the question, admittedly poorly worded. The array can be of massive size and therefore can't be declared. The elements of the array would be the result of a formula or progression which seems to be related to the index. Then, for any _k_ index, what would the value be? As such, until more information is given about the nature of the formula, the question cannot be answered.

Comment: I didn't miss it, as I see '...' in the end. But in that case, array is not a solution, and you have to do it calculatedly. You have a formula according you fill the array. Run it every time (in a no-array solution) that you look for K, and the (index+1) of the calculating loop gives the answer.

Comment: Yes, precisely, your comment in fact would make for a better answer.

Comment: It's a trade-off: memory size vs performance. If it has 10,000,000 items or 100. How many times in aminute it's done? How much it's possible to improve the 'search-by-calculate' function (maybe for a big K, start from a big index and not from 1).